# Angular JS Values selected in drop down not shown

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am using select with ng option in Angular JS.I am setting up the default value through ng-model object(Select an Option as the first item).When i click on drop down i can see the first item its being selected in the drop down but those values (Select an option) are not displayed.Could any one of you help me with that

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.form = {};
  $scope.form.options = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='myApp'>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-show="form.selected">
    Selected Option: {{form.selected}}
  </div>

  <select name="select" ng-model="form.selected">
    <option value="">---Please select---</option>
    <option ng-repeat="opt in form.options" value="{{opt}}" ng-bind="opt"></option>
  </select>
</body>

</html>
```